# How can I download and put an image in a view in Android

Tags: java, android, http, bitmap, image

I use an API (...) I receive an url that contain a png, and I have trouble to show the picture.

I have to download the picture, and to show it. I put a gesture to request an other picture, so I have to delete the older picture when the user ask the newest one (when he make the gesture on the picture)

So, I've a method that download and show the picture (but the screen still black ... ):

```
    private void downloadImage() {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        URL urlImage = new URL("http://www.google.fr/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlImage.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        Log.v("", "is showed");
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        Log.v("", "isn't");
        } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

in the onLoad, I've put

```
setContentView(R.layout.secondtab);
```

image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

and I'va declared the ImageView image before @Override.

In the xml, it's like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
    android:id="@+id/gestures" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true" android:gestureStrokeType="single" 
    android:gestureColor="#00FFFFFF"/>

<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/ivImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
/>
```

Thank you for the help :-)

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? It's hard to tell from your description what you need help with: making a connection to a url? processing the result? displaying the image once you have it? something else?

Comment: @ Ted : initial post updated.. I think I have to think differently, no? THAKS

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `image.postInvalidate()`? Or just invalidate it if you are running all of this on the UI thread.

Comment: What is your error? Is it an `OutOfMemoryException` or is your code just not showing the picture?

Answer (score 0):

My error was that there was twice the same line :

```
setContentView(R.layout.secondtab);
```

now it's running, I just have to resize it!

Thanks to StackOverFlow!